# I'm a lean, mean, bad-tag hunting machine. And [sessions] is in my sights.

Tags: discussion, tags

[sessions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sessions) is a meta tag, IMO. The asker should just tag it with whatever application's session he/she is having a problem with. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

yeah, either just the application or if necessary something like $APPLICATION-sessions. As it is it's just a meta-tag mess. Need someone with some motivation to retag them...